# What launchers support Tasker's Go Home to a paticular page?

Tags: launcher, tasker

Tasker's Go Home action has a slider that lets you select *which page* of your launcher will be displayed. Trouble is, the launcher has to be written to support this feature (specifically, it needs to recognize `net.dinglisch.android.tasker.extras.HOME_PAGE` as a parameter to the launch intent).

Anyone know which launchers support this feature? ADW doesn't and Go doesn't. Tag Home doesn't. Nova does, according to its readme, but it's ICS only (I'm still on Gingerbread). I'm willing to download every launcher to see if I can find one, but I was hoping someone would know before I resort to that.

Answer (score 1):

The now (almost) obsolete [LauncherPro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fede.launcher) supports this feature.

Comment: Would hate to have to fall back to this launcher... but it's a possibility I guess.

Comment: Is this feature that big a deal to you?

Comment: I don't really *need* it. But I don't really *need* a smartphone in the first place...